# Some questions regarding how to better use database, content providers, parsing and GitHub

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider, backend

I am a new developer and currently building a newspaper reader app. I would like to have your suggestions over these questions:

My main problems are:

1. **Better way to use databases** to collect all different newspapers+their categories.
   The first screen of the app would be a category and newspaper selection dialog box, which would offer 7-8 categories like National, World, Your City, Sports, Tech, etc and few newspapers which the user would like to read.
   Till now I have learnt using SQLite and created multiple tables in single database, but since the number of (catergories x newspaper) could be very high, how can I better manage the tables? I have seen at many places about back-end services like Google App Engine and Parse.com but I currently I have not read about them.
2. **Should I use contentproviders**? I had been searching a lot and as content providers are used when sharing the data, the only use for my app would be while making widgets.They also provide another layer of abstraction but I am still not sure whether to use them or not.
3. **Parsing**. Currently I am using XMLPullParser to get titles & links from rss files of the website. I would then use the link in JSoup parser to get the article body rather than regular webview. Is this practice right?
4. **Can I use the libraries on Github** directly? I am thinking of using Lazy Loading for downloading image thumbnails of article or using "Never Ending List" feature. Can I use the program directly or are there any steps to be taken? I couldnt find any.

It would be very helpful if you can answer any of the questions. The most important for me is the first one. Thanks!

**Little about app:**
I am building a newspaper reader app, using rss feeds of newspapers. I have a master-detail flow kind of layout, with headlines on the left and article on the right. For the headlines (and their links), I am currently using XMLPullParser to get titles & links and putting them in two arraylists. Using one of the array list I populate the listview in the left fragment with the headlines and with the onListItemClicked method I load up the link from the link-arraylist corresponding to the position. Then (right now), using the link to open a webview on right fragment (I want to change it into a better looking view, maybe by using JSoup).

Answer (score 0):

1) I would suggest using ORM library for Android to get rid of boilerplate database code. For example [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/)

4) Usually an Android library from Github is uploaded to the Maven Central repository. So if you are using Gradle or Maven build system    you can add a library dependency to your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` file. For image loading I recommend to use the amazing [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)    library from Square. As an example it can be added a the dependency to build.gradle file:

> ```
> dependencies { 
>     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.+'
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

1. Is using Google App Engine worthwhile? I dont know much about GAE right now, would I have to still use ORMLite if I use GAE?

2. I am using Eclipse right now. Do I need to download Maven build system to use the libraries then?

Comment: 1) It depends what you want. If you want to store some data on a backend it's easier to start with Parse.com. But ORMLite has nothing to do with it. It's only for mapping Java objects to SQLite database. 2) You need maven-android-plugin (https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) and maven itself (http://maven.apache.org/)

Comment: For my news reader app, I have 3 kinds of tables- 1 showing what have user the selected i.e. which category (rows) of which newspaper (column), 2 kind showing links of each category (rows) of each newspaper (column), the 3rd kind (would have 30-40 tables) having two columns, one of headlines and second of urls, it is constructed when the user selects the newspaper-category to see the headlines.
Further, using the selected link, I want the parse the article into something like how Pocket, Pulse or Feedly show them.
I think (please correct me here), to use servers to help me create the articles.